# AngularJS - filter logic from controller works, not being displayed correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use a filter that I have written in my controller to narrow down a select list using ng-options. The filter logic is working, but the results aren't getting displayed.

Here's the relevant part of my controller:

```
        $scope.ESGFilter = function() {
            var esg;
            var filteredESGs = [];

            // LOGIC GOES HERE TO POPULATE THE filteredESGs ARRAY

            console.log(filteredESGs);
            return filteredESGs;
        }]);
```

Here's the HTML:

```
    <select class="input-block-level" id="inputESG" name="inputStoch"
         ng-model="Run.ESG" 
         ng-options="econ.Id as econ.Name for econ in econData | filter:ESGFilter" size="5">
    </select>
```

I suspect the issue has to be with "filter:ESGFilter" in the HTML... I can't figure out why the array that I return from the function isn't being displayed. The function in the controller is definitely being called and the logic is working.

For reference, the console.log outputs: [Object, Object] -- when I expand the properties of these objects, I confirm that they are the ones that I want. The select list, however, displays all four objects (I'm filtering down from an array of four).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filter needs to return a true/false statement. Write your filter like this:

```
$scope.ESGFilter = function(item) {
  // if you want to keep the item return true, else false
};
```

This works because the `ngOptions` takes each item in your array and passes it to your filter function. Your example is not working because it's returning an empty array which will always resolve to a truthy value, and all objects will be accepted and not filtered.

Here's a plunk:

http://plnkr.co/edit/RfKMcXDKy1m1EGyoEpS7?p=preview

Comment: You are a God among men, thank you very much! I suppose I should have figured that out by realizing why my console.log() statement was executing so many times... I was using an angular.forEach in my logic, so I unknowlingly had a nested for loop (since the items are all passed in from ng-options anyway).